# How to reload Ajax Request while routing between pages in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, url-routing

I'm new to ReactJS and I'm trying to use [React Router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) on a project I'm working on. I'm using a nested route to load a component, but I suspect that because of the structure of my project, the nested route is not using it's handler at all. So when I use the Back button there is no history of the first ajax request, but it keeps showing the results of the second one.

I have this parent component `Competitions` which performs an ajax request:

```js
var Competitions = React.createClass({
 getInitialState: function() {
  return {
   compData: [],
   id: "",
   hide: false,
  }
},

 componentDidMount: function() {
  axios.get(this.props.source, {
   headers: {'X-Auth-Token': '********************',
              'Content-type': 'application/json'}
  })
  .then(result => {
   this.setState({compData: result.data});
  })
  .catch(error => {
   console.log(error);
  });
 },

 changeId: function (newId) {
  this.setState({
   id: newId
  });
 },

 render: function() {
  return (
   <CompTable compData={this.state.compData} id={this.state.id} onClick= {this.changeId} hide={this.state.hide}/>
  );
 }
});

module.exports = Competitions;
```

The `Competitions` component passes the results data to it's child `CompTable`

```js
var CompTable = React.createClass({

 propTypes: {
  compData:   React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
 },

 getInitialState: function() {
  return {
   showTeams: this.props.showTeams,
   hide: this.props.hide,
  };
 },

 teamsClick: function() {
  this.setState({
   showTeams: !this.props.showTeams,
   hide: !this.props.hide,
  });
 },

 handleClick: function(e) {
  this.props.onClick(e);
 },

 render: function() {
  var hide = this.state.hide;
  var list = this.props.compData.map(function (comp, i) {

  return (
   <tr key={i+1}>
    <th scope="row">{i+1}</th>
    <td className={comp.id} onClick={function() { this.teamsClick(); this.handleClick(comp.id); }.bind(this)}> <Link to={'/competitions/'+comp.league}> {comp.caption} </Link> </td>
    <td>{comp.league}</td>
    <td>{comp.numberOfTeams}</td>
   </tr>
  );
 }, this);

 if (hide) {
  return (
   <div className="row">
    <div > { this.state.showTeams ? <Teams id={this.props.id}/> : null }  </div>
   </div>
  )
 }

 else {
  return (
   <tbody>{list}</tbody>
  )
 }
});

module.exports = CompTable;
```

Inside the `CompTable` component I have a conditional render. So the first time the ajax call is made, it loads the Competitions Table and then when a competition is clicked, I grab the clicked team id and load the child component `Teams` which performs the second ajax request:

```js
var Teams = React.createClass({

 getInitialState: function() {
  return {
   teamData: [],
  }
 },

 componentWillMount: function(){
  this.dataSource();
 },

 componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps){
  this.dataSource(nextProps);
 },

 dataSource: function(props) {
  props = props || this.props;
  var url = 'http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/x/teams';
  var source = url.replace(url.split('/')[5], this.props.id);

  axios.get(source, {
   headers: {'X-Auth-Token': '********************',
            'Content-type': 'application/json'}
  })
  .then(result => {
   this.setState({teamData: result.data.teams});
  })
  .catch(error => {
   console.log(error);
  });
 },

 render: function() {
  return (
   <TeamsTable teamData={this.state.teamData}/>
  );
 }

});

module.exports = Teams;
```

I'm posting the `Index` file with the Router:

```js
var app = document.getElementById('app');

var CompetitionsWrapper = React.createClass({
 render: function () {
  return (
   <Competitions source="http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/?season=2016"/>
  );
 }
});

ReactDOM.render(
 <Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
   <IndexRoute component={Home}></IndexRoute>
   <Route path="/competitions" component={CompetitionsWrapper}>
    <Route path="/competitions/:teamLeague" component={Teams} ></Route>
   </Route>
  </Route>
 </Router>,
app);
```

Every time the competitions table loads and I'm able to load a Teams Table by clicking on a competition, when I'm using the back button there isn't a new ajax request, but I still see the loaded Teams Table and I can see from Chrome developer tools that the same team is reloaded. Is there any way to recall the Competitions ajax request when I use the back  button or is there another way to make browser history work correctly?

Comment: `componentDidMount` will not be called again unless the component unmounts first (going to a completely different route). However `componentWillReceiveProps` will fire when you hit the back button

Comment: @azium I did that and it doesn't work. Is it possible for the problem to be at the routing? If I completely remove the `handler={Teams}` nothing changes, and everything works as usual, because apparently the `Teams` component is called inside the `CompTable` and the Router doesn't use it at all.

Comment: oh.. why are you using `handler` instead of `component` ?

Comment: what version of react router are you using?

Comment: @azium you're right I shouldn't use `handler`, I use version 3.0.0., but I thought it was the same thing. I replaced it with `component` but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Problem solved. First of all the router shouldn't be nested under `CompetitionsWrapper`. I had to pass a property onclick from a grandchild to the parent and that did the trick.